# How to eliminate array items which has certain value

Tags: ruby

I have an array of `arr3 = ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "Dd,Da,Dc", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC", "dD,dC,dA"]` and  `item = ["dD"]`. I want to eliminate items which have either "dD" or "Dd".

My desired result is ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"].

I tried the following but it's not working, it doesn't filter out any items, so `arr3` stays the same:

```
arr3 = ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "Dd,Da,Dc",
        "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC", "dD,dC,dA"] 
item = ["dD"]

def eliminate (from, item) 
  item1 =  item.join
  item2 = item1.reverse
  from.select { |pair| !pair.include? item1 or !pair.include? item2} 
end

eliminate(arr3, item)
```

Comment: Please describe in what way your code is "not working".

Comment: I updated the question to include what the incorrect output is.

Comment: Is `item` always just one element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inelegant but effective ("brutto ma buono"):

```
arr3 = ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "Dd,Da,Dc", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC", "dD,dC,dA"]
item = ["dD"]
result = arr3.delete_if do |element|
  triad = element.split(",")
  triad.member?(item[0]) or triad.member?(item[0].reverse)
end
p result
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
def eliminate from, item
  from.reject { |e| e.include? item.join } &
  from.reject { |e| e.include? item.join.reverse }
end

eliminate arr3, item
# ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]
```

---

Or this one!

```
def eliminate from, item
  from.reject do |e|
    e.include?(item.join) || e.include?(item.join.reverse)
  end
end

eliminate arr3, item
# ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]
```

Comment: The original poster's code wasn't working because he was using `or` instead of `and`. But alternative implementations are cool too ;)

Comment: @Cupcake, hey, I remember you! You once helped me with a git problem <3

Answer (score 2):

change the condition to `and`

```
from.select { |pair| !pair.include? item1 and !pair.include? item2}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't working because of your condition here:

```
!pair.include? item1 or !pair.include? item2
```

You have your condition "backwards" because you're using `or` instead of `and`. You want one of these instead:

```
!pair.include?(item1) && !pair.include?(item2)
# or
!(pair.include?(item1) || pair.include?(item2))
```

This is because of a [De Morgan's boolean conversion laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws). Let's say you have two conditions `A` and `B`. Then

```
not(A or B) = not(A) and not(b)
not(A and B) = not(A) or not(B)
```

You want `pair` to not include both `item1` ***and*** `item2`, so that's why:

```
!pair.include?(item1) && !pair.include?(item2)
```

is a natural and correct way to express that.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr3.reject { |str| str =~ /#{item.first}|#{item.first.reverse}/ }
  #=> ["Ac,Ab,Aa", "Ba,Bb,Bd", "Ca,Cc,Cb", "aA,aC,aD", "bD,bA,bB", "cB,cA,cC"]
```